# Como fechar um ficheiro .bat com outro ficheiro .bat

Tags: batch, cmd

Eu tenho um ficheiro.bat a correr este código:

```
cd C:\Users\PC\Desktop\nginx-1.10.2\php
php-cgi -b 127.0.0.1:9000
```

Mas ele necessita de estar aberto enquanto é utilizado.
Há alguma forma de criar outro .bat para fechar esse?
Obrigado.

Comment: Fechar ou terminar a execução dele?

Comment: Acho que é fechar, por exemplo como se clicasse no X para fechar.

Comment: Por que fechar via script? Mesmo sendo possível, você vai gastar a mesma (talvez maior) quantidade de cliques/tempo para usar o novo .bat.

Answer (score 1):

Adicione isto no seu ficheiro bat:

```
@Echo Off
title NomeDoFicheiro.bat
```

No outro ficheiro bat que vai criar introduza isso:

```
start "" NomeDoFicheiro.bat
ping -n 10 localhost >nul
taskkill /f /im cmd.exe /fi "windowtitle eq NomeDoFicheiro.bat"
```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Eu quando acrescento 

@Echo Off
title NomeDoFicheiro.bat

O comando que tinha antes não aparece nem dá.

Comment: Vou tentar explicar melhor, eu tenho dois ficheiros .bat, um é startnginx e o outro stopnginx. O startnginx é para iniciar e ficar aberto até o utilizador não querer mais, e o stopnginx é o que vai fechar o startnginx.

Comment: Nesse caso basta só criar o seu ficheiro stopnginx.bat e introduzir o seguint scrpt: `taskkill /F /IM startnginx.bat`

Comment: Já exprimentei e não fecha

Answer (score 1):

Depois de muita pesquisa, finalmente consegui descobrir como se faz.
Este é o código do ficheiro .bat que abre:

```
title startnginx.bat
cd C:\Users\PC\Desktop\nginx-1.10.2
start nginx.exe
cd C:\Users\PC\Desktop\nginx-1.10.2\php
php-cgi -b 127.0.0.1:9000
```

E este é o código para fechar:

```
taskkill /f /im nginx.exe
Taskkill /fi "windowtitle eq startnginx.bat"
```

Basicamente o ficheiro .bat que abre tem que se atribuir um título para poder procurar depois pelo título no ficheiro .bat que é para fechar.

Obrigado a todos que me ajudaram.

Comment: Marque como resposta para poder fechar a pergunta.